# Regex string allows emails without TLD

Tags: regex

I have the following regex for validating emails:

```
/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*(\+[a-z0-9-]+)?@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i
```

The only problem I see is that it allows emails without TLD, such as:
example@domain

How can I fix this? Any other suggestion of improvement is also appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Replace `(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$` with `(\.[a-z0-9-]+)+$`

Comment: Wow, that was quick, thanks! Please do post as answer so I can accept it. Any other suggestions at all for my email validation, or would you say it's complete?